# XOR encryption / symmetric encryption in C

Tags: c

I'm just trying to encrypt the text entered by the user via xor and to decrypt it again with a given key.

Although the text and the final key are entered, cryptic characters are constantly being added outside of the input (see picture below, input was hallohallo).

unfortunately I do not find the error hope one of you can help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
int i = 0;
char eingabe[99];     //Text input by the user
char key[99]="930901";//Encryption key
char output[99];
char decrypt[99];

printf("eingabe\n");
scanf(" %s", &eingabe);
size_t eingabelen = strlen(eingabe);
printf("string=%d, von eingabelen\n",eingabelen);


for(i = 0; i < eingabelen; i++)
{
    output[i] = eingabe[i]^key[i]; //XOR verschlüsselung
    printf("\n%d",i);
}
printf("\noutput XORed: %s\n", output);
//printf("\n");



for(i = 0; i < eingabelen; i++)
{
        decrypt[i] = output[i]^key[i]; //XOR entschlüsselung
}
printf("Un XORed: %s\n\n", decrypt);
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I did not check the link: Please provide text output as text, not as an image.

Comment: I recommend to translate everything to English. Trust me, it gets you more, better answers, faster.

Comment: `printf()` and the other C functions that handle strings run until they find a NUL character (`\0`). Your string miss it, therefore `printf()` prints more than you want.

Comment: You're not terminating `output` with \0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading past the string length of `key` (6). You'll need to use e.g. the modulus operator (`%`) to keep reading only up to 6 characters (or however long your key is), e.g. like below.

In addition, you'll need to zero-terminate `decrypt`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  int i = 0;
  char eingabe[99] = "This is a test string";
  char key[99] = "930901"; // Encryption key
  char output[99];
  char decrypt[99];
  size_t eingabelen = strlen(eingabe);
  size_t key_len = strlen(key);

  for (i = 0; i < eingabelen; i++) {
    output[i] = eingabe[i] ^ key[i % key_len]; // XOR verschlüsselung
  }
  printf("\noutput XORed: %s\n", output);

  for (i = 0; i < eingabelen; i++) {
    decrypt[i] = output[i] ^ key[i % key_len]; // XOR entschlüsselung
  }
  decrypt[i] = 0;  // Zero terminate
  printf("Un XORed: %s\n\n", decrypt);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

This outputs

```
output XORed: m[YJXJQDTJGJDCP]W
Un XORed: This is a test string
```

(However, there's still the issue that if `key` and `eingabe` have common characters, the result of `XOR` will be 0, and your "output XORed" will print a truncated result, since `printf` stops printing at the first zero byte, as C strings work.)

Comment: Also need to set output[i] to '\0' after the for loop.

Comment: @Harun Just added that too.

Comment: XORing printable characters does not realiably result in printable characters, that is the more general problem which includes the "could end up 0" which you mention.

Comment: The bytes after "930901\0" in `key` are not uninitialized, they're initialized to 0. From 6.7.8.21 in the standard: "If there are ... fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration."

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I'll try again to improve